# How can I run executable in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have folder "destination/" and inside the destination folder, it contains executable grade1. My current directory is "destination/"

I'm Trying to run

```
for i in FILES/*; do ./grade1 $i done
```

Which it keep says

```
./grade1 no such file or directory
```

Weird part is that, when I just copy the code to command line and run it, it works fine. Problem only arises when I do it in shell script

Comment: How is the script being run? In particular, what working directory is the script being run with?

Comment: Try mentioning the full path in the script like `for i in /path/to/FILES/*; do /path/to/grade1 $i; done`

Comment: You can call `pwd` command inside your foreach loop to know where you are.

Comment: doing ./grade1 should work.  Your directory must be incorrect or permissions wrong.

Comment: Well working directory is "destination" in which every executable is located. Worst thing is same command works in command line but not in shell script

Comment: Then add it to your `PATH` (e.g. at the beginning of your script add `export PATH="/absolute/path/to/destination:$PATH"`) and then `do grade1 "$i"` -- don't forget the quotes.

Comment: Show `ls -al grade1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that grade1 **really** is in your current working directory, as you claim. I suggest that you verify this also check the permissions of your executable. Extend your code to

```
echo current directory is $PWD
ls -l grade1
for i in FILES/*; do ./grade1 $i done
```

This should reveal the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to fix this problem might be to start using FULL path of grade1 executable file

```
for i in FILES/*; do {FULL_PATH}/grade1 $i done
```